# Number of ways of populating a binary tree to make it a bst

Tags: binary-tree, combinatorics

We are given a set of n distinct elements and an unlabeled binary tree with n nodes.In how many can we populate the tree with given set so that it becomes a binary search tree?

Comment: Does a linked list count as a (degenerate) BST?

Comment: I think the answer should be one if the root node is fixed, but I'm confused what will happen if the root node is allowed to change.

Answer (score 1):

when a "tree" would be given for a program(in any language) - it means the root node address will be provided for traversal.
Hence according to me since the "Root Node" is provided means the tree structure is already build and fixed into one type.

so i think there can be only one possible way

Answer (score 0):

If by unlabeled you mean there's no specified root node, let `G = {G[1]..G[n]}` be the set of graphs of the original unlabeled tree rooted at vertices `1 ... n` respectively.

Then for each graph `G[i]` there is exactly one way to populate the tree (why? -- consider what value must be in the root of the tree, and descend recursively).

Once you can show that, the answer must be `k`, the number of mutually nonisomorphic graphs in the set `G`

Comment: I think by unlabeled they mean structure of the tree is fixed, therefore the root node is fixed.

Comment: The choices for the answer are a) 0 b) 1 c)n! d) n th catalan's number.Which among these do you think can be the correct answer?

Comment: then it would be nth catalan number -- that counts the number of binary trees.